# how to hide user credentials in http headers - angular2 application

Tags: angular, http, security, authentication

i have an angular 2 application . It depends entirely on http calls. This application gets triggered from a main application and gets user id through url. It doesn't have it's login page. To protect all the http calls i need to send an id and password in http headers. The only way i can get these details is to save this sensitive information in a local json config file and get it through http call before making any http call which is not protected. If some one looks at the network they can easily see the id and password in response. Everything we save in front end can be accessed some or the other way. How to hide the id and password from user ? any suggestions ?

Comment: you should use post method and send the data in the body not in the header.

Comment: Thanks . but still it can be seen in network trace as http request body. Is there a way to hide the request body ? Main concern is how can we secure http call made to get user details from json file. its visible in response body.

Comment: Is there a good reason that the backend doesn't support https?

Comment: You _need_ HTTPS. As a professional I would never agree to put something so insecure into the hands of consumers who think their data is protected. It would be a breach of ethics.

Comment: prod environment has https. But even in prod,  i am able to check the details through inspect element -> Network  -> request body

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, if you want to protect the content of your http requests (and responses) from prying eyes, you should use https